# How do I display my MVC .cshtml and open an Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, response

So I have an issue I want display a View to indicate to the end user that their request to download/open an Excel spreadsheet is processing, and then I want to have the Excel spreadsheet open, and the View close.

Currently, I get a blank Screen and then the Excel opens

so 3 things:

1. Display View with a Preloader
2. Open/Download an Excel Spreadsheet
3. Close the View, after spreadsheet opens

Here is the View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CoursePriceHistory";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Course Price History</h2>

<img src="~/Images/loading.gif" />
```

Here is the ActionResult from the Controller:

```
   public ActionResult CoursePriceHistory()
        {
            // Sql Statement to provide parameters for Quarter Year (MIN/MAX)
            DAL.QuarterYear qy = new DAL.QuarterYear();
             
            var min = qy.getMIN();
            var max = qy.getMAX();
        
            ReportExecutionService rs = new ReportExecutionService();
            rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

            // Render arguments
            byte[] result = null;
            string fileName = @"\\department.chicagobooth.edu\Test\something.pdf";
            string reportPath = @"/Sam - Faculty and Course Reports/Course Price History";
            string format = "EXCEL";
            string historyID = null;

            string encoding;
            string mimeType;
            string extension;
            ReportService.Warning[] warnings = null;
            string[] streamIDs = null;

            ExecutionInfo execInfo = new ExecutionInfo();
            ExecutionHeader execHeader = new ExecutionHeader();

            rs.ExecutionHeaderValue = execHeader;

            execInfo = rs.LoadReport(reportPath, historyID);
            ParameterValue[] parameters = new ParameterValue[3];
            parameters[0] = new ParameterValue();
            parameters[0].Name = "StartQuarterYear";
            parameters[0].Value = min;
            parameters[1] = new ParameterValue();
            parameters[1].Name = "EndQuarterYear";
            parameters[1].Value = max;

            String SessionId = rs.ExecutionHeaderValue.ExecutionID;

            rs.SetExecutionParameters(parameters, "en-us");

            result = rs.Render(format, null, out extension, out encoding, out mimeType, out warnings, out streamIDs);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(result);

            // Write PDF
            Response.Clear();
            
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=Course Price History");
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/Excel");
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            Response.OutputStream.Write(ms.ToArray(), 0, ms.ToArray().Length);
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Flush();

            Response.Close();

            return View();
        }
```

Comment: To know when the Excel workbook has finished loading, you would need access to the processes of the target computer. So as I see it, this is not possible.

Comment: well, that makes sense and lesser of the issues

Comment: Yeah, unless you are allowed to install an app on the client, that monitors the excel processes, and waits until an excel window with the expected title/file is open. This is how I solved the issue.

Comment: If it is a macro enabled workbook, you can make that workbook check if your 'waiting screen' is open in the browser, and redirect it. But this approach is usually not possible these days, because of the security policies implemented by the customers, i.e. you are not allowed to use the libraries that you need from VBA.

Comment: Thank you, but my main issue is how to display the preloader screen, prior to opening the Excel, maybe it can't be done. I don't know

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236983/gowiser-and-paul-t-rykiel